# `this` is undefined in expressJS route handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**groups.js**

```
class groupsCtrl {
  constructor() {
    this.info = "test";
  }

  get(res, req) {
    console.log("LOG ! ", JSON.stringify(this));
  }
}
module.exports = new groupsCtrl(); //singleton
```

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var groupsCtrl = require('controllers/api_admin/groups.js');
router.get('/groups/', groupsCtrl.get);
```

This logs `LOG ! undefined`

How can I have access to `this` in my controller class ?

Comment: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to bind the method to the instance.

One solution:

```
router.get('/groups/', groupsCtrl.get.bind(groupsCtrl));
```

Another solution:

```
constructor() {
  this.info = "test";
  this.get  = this.get.bind(this);
}
```

Or use something like [`es6bindall`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6bindall) (which basically does the same as the code above, but is perhaps a bit more useful when you need to bind more than one method).

Comment: Thank you :) But I don't understand how a class method can be invoked without a reference to itself ? I find this confusing to need to explicitly bind it

Comment: @IggY, you need to explicitly bind it only if you don't pass context with it, like here `router.get('/groups/', groupsCtrl.get)` you passing only some sort of `reference to function 'groupsCtrl.get'`, without it's context, thus, if you _want_ that function called in specific context, you should manually attach it with `groupsCtrl.get.bind(groupsCtrl)`. It's like passing hidden `self` when calling class-method in oop c-like language, and passing only method-pointer...

Comment: @IggY `.get` returns reference to the function found in the prototype chain (or undefined). You don't invoke "class methods" in JS, you invoke functions, which happen to be "bound to context" when you use `object.method` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I get it. Still find it wierd though

Comment: It works but is very tedious when you have 10 methods for example... I recommend to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453105/11705679

Answer (score 11):

```
class groupsCtrl {
    constructor() {
        this.info = 'test';
    }

    get = (res, req) => {
        console.log('LOG ! ', JSON.stringify(this));
    };
}
```

You can just use arrow function to avoid boilerplate code

Comment: this works for javascript but not for typescript :(

Comment: @DiegoUlloa This should work for Typescript. I just tested it.

Comment: At least did for me

Comment: Yeah works with instantiated methods (non-statics)

Answer (score 4):

**2020 Update**

- While both solutions posted by @robertkiep get the job dont, I want to emphasize that both look ugly and are not maintainable
- Method 1 which does router.get('/groups/', groupsCtrl.get.bind(groupsCtrl)) looks really ugly when you have a large number of routes
- Method 2 gets cumbersome when your controller has many routes
- Since your example has only 1 route let me illustrate the problem

**Using method 2**

```
class AuthController {
  constructor({ db, pgp, logger }) {
    super({ db, pgp, logger })
    this.postLogin = this.postLogin.bind(this)
    this.postLogout = this.postLogout.bind(this)
    this.postSignup = this.postSignup.bind(this)
    this.postForgot = this.postForgot.bind(this)
    this.getReset = this.getReset.bind(this)
    this.postReset = this.postReset.bind(this)
  }

  postLogin(req, res, next) {
    
  }

  postLogout(req, res, next) {

  }

  async postSignup(req, res, next) {
    
  }

  async postForgot(req, res, next) {
    
  }

  async getReset(req, res, next) {
    
  }

  async postReset(req, res, next) {
    
  }
}
```

Each time you add a new method, the constructor needs to be updated further

**Method 3**

This in my opinion is a lot cleaner, doesnt need maintenance and you can keep adding methods as you want

- The idea is to use the Object.hasOwnPropertyName to get an array of all method names and then bind them programmatically
- For example if you write Object.hasOwnPropertyName(AuthController.prototype) it will give you ALL NON STATIC methods in an array
- In the example above you will get ['constructor', 'postLogin', 'postLogout'...]
- If you call Object.hasOwnPropertyName(AuthController) you get STATIC methods
- Lets invoke them programmatically

This controller requires little to no maintenance except keep the static and non static methods in mind, remove the constructor by filtering it out and then invoke bind on each

```
class AuthController {
  constructor({ db, pgp, logger }) {
    super({ db, pgp, logger })
    this.postLogin = this.postLogin.bind(this)
    this.postLogout = this.postLogout.bind(this)
    this.postSignup = this.postSignup.bind(this)
    this.postForgot = this.postForgot.bind(this)
    this.getReset = this.getReset.bind(this)
    this.postReset = this.postReset.bind(this)

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(AuthController.prototype)
      .filter((propertyName) => propertyName !== 'constructor')
      .forEach((method) => (this[method] = this[method].bind(this)))
  }

  postLogin(req, res, next) {
    
  }

  postLogout(req, res, next) {

  }

  async postSignup(req, res, next) {
    
  }

  async postForgot(req, res, next) {
    
  }

  async getReset(req, res, next) {
    
  }

  async postReset(req, res, next) {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you make this work in Typescript? other than prefixing the forEach() with a // @ts-ignore comment/directive ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is great, I want to add a little bit to help clarify:

Assume we have a class:

```
class TClass {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.arg = arg
  }
  test() {
    console.log(this.arg)
  }
}
```

This will NOT work:

```
const t = new TClass("test")
const method = t.test  // method is simply a reference without context
method() // 'this' is not defined
```

This will work:

```
const t = new TClass("test")
t.test() // log 'test'
```

And the reason is like the comments above, the reference to the function doesn't have a context

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when using "traditional" functions, the "**this**" keyword points to something different.

Change this

```
get(res, req) {
    console.log("LOG ! ", JSON.stringify(this));
  }
```

to
Change this

```
get = (res, req) => {
    console.log("LOG ! ", JSON.stringify(this));
  }
```

And should work