# "this" is undefined when try to pass class methods in router as middleware _ express

Tags: node.js, express

I think my problem is related to javascript itself if I am correct. I am trying to use this keyword inside my middleware but I am getting undefined. why?

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor(foo){
        this.foo =  foo
    }
    testFoo(req, res, next){
        console.log(this.foo) // undefined
    }
}

let class_test = new SomeClass("some data")


app.get('/', class_test.testFoo, (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));
```

Comment: You will have to bind the object. Check this answer - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680450/this-is-undefined-in-expressjs-route-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
app.get(
  '/', 
  (req, res, next) => class_test.testFoo(req, res, next),
  (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!')
);
```

Comment: why this is happening?

Comment: @BabakAbadkheir because `this` is evaluated to some internal `this` from `express`: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/3yux6i/why_does_using_bindthis_within_settimeout/cygu9zh?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3